# Medida de algoritmo

Tags: python, python-3.x, diccionarios

En la línea 4 del código me da el siguiente error : 'dict' has not attribute 'append'.

Tengo que añadir al diccionario `measures` una serie de entradas donde las claves son el restultado de concatenar el tipo de generación de instancia (cadena de texto) junto con el nombre del algoritmo (separados por ":") del diccionario `algorithms`. El valor asociado a cada clave es, inicialmente, una lista vacía.

```
def measure_algorithms(algorithms, gen_instances, sizes):

        measures = {}

        for key in gen_instances:
            measures.append (gen_instances(key=[])) 
        for talla in sizes : 
            gen_instances(talla)
            for algoritmo in algorithms:
                tiempo = measure_time(algorithms, gen_instances)
                measures.append(tiempo)

        return measures
```

Comment: ¿Que error? agrega el mensaje que recibes. Saludos.

Comment: Añadido el mensaje.

Comment: Evidentemente, un diccionario no tiene ningún método llamado `append`.

Answer (score 0):

Este tema ya esta resuelto,
Los diccionarios en python no te tienen la acción `append` disponible, sólo las listas.

1º Opción
  Asignar nuevos valores a sus respectivas claves

```py
mydict = {}
mydict['item'] = input_value
```

2º Opción
  Usar una lista en su lugar

```py
mylist = []
mylist.append(input_value)
```

Fuente: [StackOverflow -  Python AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48234473/python-attributeerror-dict-object-has-no-attribute-append)